# Do jQuery Attribute/Value changes trigger corresponding event handlers bound to the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

For instance if I select a radio button through jQuery code does this fire the onClick event for that particular input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because that's not a *click*. You can trigger an event on an element with the `trigger` method, or trigger any registered event handlers *without* triggering the default action using the `triggerHandler` method.

Comment: Ok, bad example what about onChange? my question was more relating to in general would any such events occur.

Comment: No again, because the "change" event is defined to be triggered when the data in a field is changed *by the user*. As far as I know, all events have similar caveats; they won't be triggered by code unless you go out of your way to simulate user interaction.

Comment: That makes sense, the trigger methods works well thanks hobbs.